# How can I set up custom Dynamic DNS on a ZyXel VMG3925?

Tags: router, dynamic-dns

I have a ZyXel VMG3925-B10C router, which I'm trying to set up with DNS Made Easy.

The standard URL syntax for this is https://cp.dnsmadeeasy.com/servlet/updateip?password=mypass&id=1007&ip=12.13.14.15 (the [docs](https://dnsmadeeasy.com/technology/dynamic-dns/) also suggest a username field, but I've found this is not needed.)

[image: ZyXel VMG3925-B10C Dynamic DNS interface]

The [manual](https://download.zyxel.com/VMG3925-B10C/user_guide/VMG3925-B10C_V5.13_5.50.pdf) sadly neglects how to set up user-defined DNS providers.  In particular, it doesn't define what the placeholders for things like the IP address should look like.  (I've found this crucial information to be missing from other routers' manuals too..)

The closest page I can find (for a [ZyXel 5501](https://www.dynu.com/DynamicDNS/IPUpdateClient/Zyxel-5501)) suggests `<username>`, `<password>`, `<domain>` and `<ipaddr>` for the placeholder names.

I have tried the following values, but just seem to get a "Not Accepted" error, which seems to be the standard response for pretty much anything I try.

- Dynamic DNS: Enable
- Service Provider: DNS user defined
- Connection type: HTTPS
- URL update: `cp.dnsmadeeasy.com/servlet/updateip?username=<username>&password=<password>&id=<domain>&ip=<ipaddr>`
- Host/Domain Name: (the numeric ID assigned to my DNS record)
- Password: (the password I have set for the record)

Comment: *"The docs also suggest a username field, but I've found this is not needed."* - How is DNSMadeEasy supposed to differentiate between your account and others?

Comment: It knows (or perhaps, doesn't care) which account the record belongs to.  But it will only update the record if the password is correct, and the password for that record can only be set by someone with access to the account.

Answer (score 1):

I use DuckDNS and I managed it by making sure to not use tokens in the URL but hardcoding things. If you leave off the IP parameter, the DDNS provider calculates it based on the call. The user name needed to be my DuckDNS user name and the password was a token provided to me by DuckDNS. Hope that helps.